# Neumann problem for a circle.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

We consider the interior neumann problem : $$\nabla^{2} u =0\:\:\:, \:\:r<R$$

$$ \dfrac{\partial u}{\partial n}=\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial r}=f(\theta)\:\:,\:\:r=R\:\:,\:\: 0<\theta<2\pi$$

We first establish the fact which as the solution says is the compatibility condition : $$\int_B fds=0$$ 
which is established using Green's second formula. Now the solution proceeds as follows :

(1) The compatibility condition obtained above can be written as $$R \int_0^{2\pi} f(\theta) d\theta=0$$

(2) In the case of the dirichlet problem of the circle , the solution of the laplace equation is given as : $$u(r,\theta) = \dfrac{a_0}{2} + \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}r^{k}(a_k cosk\theta + b_k sink\theta)$$

(3) Differentiating with respect to r and applying the boundary conditions we obtain : $$\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial r}(R,\theta) = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}kR^{k-1}(a_k cosk\theta + b_k sink\theta) = f(\theta)$$

(4) Now the expression of $f(\theta)$ in a series of the form (3) is possible only by the virtue of the compatibility condition since : $$a_0 = \dfrac{1}{\pi} \int_0^{2\pi} f(\tau) d \tau = 0$$

The rest of the proof was okay , can anyone explain the points (1) and (4) ?

Like in (1) are we changing the variable into $\theta$ ? If yes , then how is $R$ there ?

And I have no idea about (4). Kindly help !

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0):

The integral in (1) is transformed into polar co-ordinates by considering the " arc-length " relation. $ds$ here is the arc length. $R$ is the radius of the region. So , using $ \theta = \dfrac{l}{r}$ , where $l$ is the arc length and $r$ is the radius . Thus we get $ \theta = \dfrac{ds}{R}$ . Substituting this gives the result.

(4) actually tells the value of the constant $a_0$. That's all.

Comment: $ d\theta = \dfrac{ds}{R}$